# Call shell script through ssh from local script and exit ssh

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sh

I have one shell script in than I want to call shell script through ssh.
Shell script should execute and connection should close,
But for me problem is scripts executes but control not return to parent script. i have to do `control-C` , then next part of my shell scripts executes.

my code is:

```
ssh -f hostname "sh /appl/gfh/hghh/management_scripts.sh dev start"
```

when i execute this it will stop here.

```
[INFO] Consumer started successfully.
```

when i do `control-C` next part of my parent script get executes.

Comment: Do: `ssh -f hostname "sh -c '/appl/gfh/hghh/management_scripts.sh dev start >/dev/null 2>&1 &'"`

Comment: Its working using above command.